# How to use regexp using controlled looping in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to grep the values starting with "1. Virtualization" to "2.Virtualization" using regular expression in perl. There are lot of data in between 1.Virutalization and 2.Virtualization in an array.

Sample of my array contents as shown below.
"1. Virtualization Capacity Management Number of incidents as a result of poor performance 0 999 10 5 4 Cost of production of Capacity Plan 10K 100K 80K 30K 10K Number of unplanned purchases of capacity 0 999 15 10 5 2.Virtualization Finance Management Number of incidents as a result of poor performance 0 999 10 5 4 Cost of production of Capacity Plan 10K 100K 80K 30K 10K"

How can I write a controlled loop which greps values between 1. and 2. In between 1 and 2 it should even grep the data "Cost of production of Capacity Plan 10K 100K 80K 30K 10K" and put in one array location.

I tried writing some piece of code was not able to understand how to write a controlled loop. Can anybody help me out with this problem.

```
foreach (@array) { 
    if ($_ =~ /\d+\.\s+Virtualization.*/) { #greps values starting in 1. Virtualizaton
         push (@node_level1, "$_");         #stores in the node_level1
    } elsif ($_ =~ /(\%\s+.*)/) {  #greps values beginning with % Number of Nodes 
       # print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: input data is not clear, where is '%Number of nodes'?

Comment: Is that data all one long line, or is it separate lines. Your question doesn't make that clear. I thought it was a formatting thing (not indenting four spaces before literal lines) but it appears you've put it in one line in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a state holder:

```
my $state = 0;

foreach (@array) { 
    if ($_ =~ /1.\s+Virtualization/) {
         $state = 1;
    } elsif (($state == 1) and ($_ =~ /2.\s+Virtualization/)) {
       $state = 0;
    } elsif ($state == 1) {
       push (@node_level1, $_);         #stores in the node_level1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an automagical operator in perl to do the same thing as perreal's answer, the [flip-flop operator](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/18/variables.html):

```
foreach (@array) { 
    if (/1.\s+Virtualization/../2.\s+Virtualization/) {
       push (@node_level1, $_);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a most elegant solution, if it wouldn't include the element matching `/[12].\s+Virt.../` as well. The flip-flop is true when the entry or the exit condition matches, so both bounding elements are *included* in the output, unlike in perreals answer.